# Reducir y posicionar correctamente la imagen del carrito de compras

Tags: javascript, html, css

Me estanqué en una parte de código en la cual no logro reducir las imágenes que agrego al carrito de compras, además no puedo lograr que a medida que se agregan elementos las imágenes no se sobre-posicionen. Comparto todo mi código:

```js
let allContainerCart = document.querySelector('.shop-content');

let containerBuyCart = document.querySelector('.card-items')

let buyThings = [];


loadEventListener()

function loadEventListener(){

    allContainerCart.addEventListener('click',addProduct);
    
}

function addProduct(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    
    if (e.target.classList.contains('add-cart')) {
    
    const selectProduct = e.target.parentElement;

    readTheContent(selectProduct);

    }
}

function readTheContent(product){

    const infoProduct = {

        image: product.querySelector('.product-img').src,
        title: product.querySelector('.product-title').textContent,
        price: product.querySelector('.price').textContent,
        id: product.querySelector('a').getAttribute('data-id'),
        amount: 1

    }

    buyThings = [...buyThings, infoProduct];

    loadHtml();

    console.log(infoProduct)

}

function loadHtml(){

    buyThings.forEach(product => {
        
        const {image, title, price, amount, id} = product;

        const row = document.createElement('div');

        row.classList.add('product-box');

        row.innerHTML = `
            
            <img src="${image}" alt="" class="product-img">
            <h2 class="product-title">${title}</h2>
            </div>
            <span class="price">${price}}</span>
            <a href="#" class="add-cart" data-id="${id}" >Añadir</a>
            <h6>Cantidad: ${amount}</h6> 

        `

        containerBuyCart.appendChild(row);

    });

}
```

```css
.nav{

    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 20px 0;

}

.container{

    max-width: 1068px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;

}

.logo{

    font-size: 1.1rem;
    color: var(--color-violeta-fuerte);
    font-weight: 400;
    text-decoration: none;

}

.count-product{

    position: absolute;
    right: 3rem;

}


.cart-products{

    position: absolute!important;
    width: 39px;
    height: 38px;
    right: 1rem;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.2rem;
    right: 2rem;
    top: 82px;
    padding: 0 18px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
    min-width: 290px;
    display: none;


}

.cart{
    width: 39px;
    height: 38px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.cart:hover{
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    transition-duration: .5s;
}

#close-x{

    color: var(--color-rojo);
    font-weight: 900;
    background: var(--color-gris);
    padding: .2rem;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;

}

#close-x:hover{

    color: var(--color-rojo);
    background: var(--color-negro);
    padding: .3rem;

}

#cart-icon{

    font-size: 1.8rem;
    cursor: pointer;

}

section{

    padding: 4rem 0 3rem;
    margin-top: 2.5rem;

}

.section-title{

    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;

}

.shop{

    margin-top: 2rem;

}

.shop-content{

    padding-top: 170px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;


}

.shop-content .product-img{

    width: 20vw;
    height: 40vh;
    padding: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: .5rem;

}

.product-box{

    position: relative;

}

.product-box:hover{

    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid var(--color-gris-oscuro);
    transition: .4s;

}

.product-title{

    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: .5rem;
    text-align: center;

}

.price{

    font-weight: 500;

}


.add-cart{

    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: var(--color-gris-oscuro);
    color: var(--color-blanco);
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;

}

.add-cart:hover{

    background: var(--color-violeta-fuerte);

}
```

```html
<body>

    <header>

        <div class="nav container">

            <a href="#" class="logo">E-Commerce</a>
            <img onmouseover="showCart(this)" class="cart" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAYAAADgdz34AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAR5JREFUSEvN1cExBUEUheHvRYAMiAARIAIywJYFIkAEbNgiAmRABIgAESAC6qqeV2PevOmuGqOczSz6zv379JnbMzKwRgP396eAz+TmHZc4+A13dQcVoOq7hru+kLYj2scJbrExBGAWb6nxAl76QKaFHBls9mj8iOV4fxpgCQ89AK+Y7wLEWuxiEdvpqyrhVc6PcZQDbOEigb7tZhTZPSOe4+xygxYzMZPOMxx1qdrQPVarwhzgFHu4QjToUszMSvNIc4AIKmyH5hCO2lTVfaRwx3U5QDS7wXq6OsJRmyLQwzanJYCY5utcwml94nopAdQ/2S7OE2J+fqgUUGhgsqwUcIYdnGO30aZrrfiHU7/Km5vqWisGDO5g8Az+L+ALYZk0GaU3ojwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" alt="carrito">
            <p class="count-product">0</p>

        </div>

        <div class="cart-products" id="products-id">
            
            <p class="close-btn" id= 'close-x' onclick="closeBtn()">X</p>
            
            <h3>Mi carrito</h3>
            
            <div class="card-items">

            </div>
            
            <h2><strong class="price-total">0</strong></h2>
        
        </div>

    </header>



    <section class="products">

        <h2 class="section-title">Tienda de Productos</h2>
    
        <div class="shop-content">

            <div class="cart-items"> </div>

            <div class="product-box">

                <div>
                     <img src="imagenes/taladro.png" alt="Taladro" class="product-img">
                     <h2 class="product-title">Taladro 13mm</h2>
                 </div>
                <span class="price">$15.000</span>
                <a href="#" class="add-cart" data-id="1" >Añadir</a>
                <h6>Cantidad: 1</h6> 
            </div>

            <div class="product-box">

                <div>
                    <img src="imagenes/taladro-2.png" alt="Taladro" class="product-img">
                    <h2 class="product-title">Taladro 10mm</h2>
                </div>
                <span class="price">$13.000</span>
                <a href="#" class="add-cart" data-id="1" >Añadir</a>
                <h6>Cantidad: 1</h6> 
            </div>

            <div class="product-box">

                <div>
                     <img src="imagenes/amoladora.png" alt="Amoladora" class="product-img">
                     <h2 class="product-title">Amoladora Angular</h2>
                </div>
                <span class="price">$9.999</span>
                <a href="#" class="add-cart" data-id="1" >Añadir</a>
                <h6>Cantidad: 1</h6> 
            </div>

            <div class="product-box">

                <div>
                    <img src="imagenes/Grasera Manual.png" alt="Grasera" class="product-img">
                    <h2 class="product-title">Grasera Manual</h2>
                </div>  
                <span class="price">$13.000</span>
                <a href="#" class="add-cart" data-id="1" >Añadir</a>
                <h6>Cantidad: 1</h6> 
            </div>

            <div class="product-box">

                <div>
                    <img src="imagenes/set-juego-de-herramientas.png" alt="Herramientas" class="product-img">
                    <h2 class="product-title">Set Juego De Herramientas</h2>
                </div>
                <span class="price">$12.000</span>
                <a href="#" class="add-cart" data-id="1" >Añadir</a>
                <h6>Cantidad: 1</h6> 
            </div>

            <div class="product-box">

                <div>
                    <img src="imagenes/cepillo-electrico.png" alt="Cepillo" class="product-img">
                    <h2 class="product-title">Cepillo Eléctrico</h2>
                </div>
                <span class="price">$25.000</span>
                <a href="#" class="add-cart" data-id="1" >Añadir</a>
                <h6>Cantidad: 1</h6> 
            </div>

            <div class="product-box">

                <div>
                    <img src="imagenes/cortadora-porcelanato.png" alt="Cortadora" class="product-img">
                    <h2 class="product-title">Cortadora Porcelanato</h2>
                </div>
                <span class="price">$20.000</span>
                <a href="#" class="add-cart" data-id="1" >Añadir</a>
                <h6>Cantidad: 1</h6> 
            </div>

            <div class="product-box">

                <div>
                     <img src="imagenes/Sierra-circular.png" alt="Sierra" class="product-img">
                     <h2 class="product-title">Sierra Circular</h2>
                </div>
                <span class="price">$12.000</span>
                <a href="#" class="add-cart" data-id="1" >Añadir</a>
                <h6>Cantidad: 1</h6> 
            </div>

            <div class="product-box">

                <div>
                     <img src="imagenes/lijadora-orbital.png" alt="Lijadora" class="product-img">
                     <h2 class="product-title">Lijadora Orbital</h2>
                </div>
                <span class="price">$9.999</span>
                <a href="#" class="add-cart" data-id="1" >Añadir</a>
                <h6>Cantidad: 1</h6> 
            </div>

            <div class="product-box">

                <div>
                    <img src="imagenes/soldadora.png" alt="Soldadora" class="product-img">
                    <h2 class="product-title">Soldadora</h2>
                </div>
                <span class="price">$20.000</span>
                <a href="#" class="add-cart" data-id="1" >Añadir</a>
                <h6>Cantidad: 1</h6> 
            </div>

            <div class="product-box">

                <div>
                    <img src="imagenes/dobladora-de-estribos.png" alt="Dobladora" class="product-img">
                    <h2 class="product-title">Dobladora de Estribos</h2>
                </div>
                <span class="price">$9.999</span>
                <a href="#" class="add-cart" data-id="1" >Añadir</a>
                <h6>Cantidad: 1</h6> 
            </div>

            <div class="product-box">

                <div>
                    <img src="imagenes/hidrolavadora.png" alt="hidrolavadora" class="product-img">
                    <h2 class="product-title">Taladro</h2>
                </div>
                <span class="price">$15.000</span>
                <a href="#" class="add-cart" data-id="1" >Añadir</a>
                <h6>Cantidad: 1</h6> 
            </div>

       
        </div>

    </section>
    
    <script>
        function showCart(x){
            document.getElementById("products-id").style.display = "block";
        }
        function closeBtn(){
             document.getElementById("products-id").style.display = "none";
        }

    </script>
    
    <script src='archivos js\e-commerce.js'></script>


</body>
```

No sé si el problema radica en el código JS o en el CSS.

Sé que di position: absolute al carrito pero no lograba que quede en la posición que necesitaba de otra forma.

Intenté utilizar .style en código js pero tampoco pude lograr reducir las imágenes.

Comment: ¿En la función loadHTML() que div estás cerrando con ese `</div>` que aparece?  A ver si eso te está cerrando cosas antes de tiempo. Por otra parte mira de agregar `style="width: 150px;"` como atributo a las imágenes del carrito para forzar su tamaño más reducido.

Comment: Te extrañaba masterguru :) , si me el </div> está demás. Y ahora agrego el width de 150px

Comment: Puse     image.style='width: 150px' pero no me lo reduce

Comment: Me referia dentro del loadHTML de este modo: `<img src="${image}" style="width: 150px;" alt="" class="product-img">` pues es la función que usas en el carrito.

Comment: Perfecto, lo único malo es que las imágenes se sobreposicionan entre sí

Comment: Pega una captura de esa sobreposición, pues no se si te refieres al carrito o a la lista de productos, y no tengo las imágenes para reproducirlo.

Comment: https://ibb.co/6JSg68P  . Hay 2 problemas, el primero es que se sobreposicionan y el segundo es que añado un producto y me sale bien pero si añado un segundo, me agrega además del primero, otra vez el primero y segundo, luego el tercero me agrega el primero, el primero y segundo, el primero, segundo y tercero.

Comment: El primer problema lo solucionas poniendo esto: `<div class="cart-products" id="products-id" style="background-color:white; z-index:100;">` y quitando el `height: 38px;` de la clase **cart-products** en tu CSS

Comment: Está mucho mejor, y por último para que no se repitan los elementos no sé como hacer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En resumen, estos son los cambios que sugiero que hagas para arreglar todos esos problemas:

1. Eliminar el `</div>` sobrante de este cacho de código de la función loadHTML():

```
row.innerHTML = `
            
            <img src="${image}" alt="" class="product-img">
            <h2 class="product-title">${title}</h2>
            </div>
            <span class="price">${price}}</span>
            <a href="#" class="add-cart" data-id="${id}" >Añadir</a>
            <h6>Cantidad: ${amount}</h6> 

        `
```

2. Dentro de la misma función, agregar `style="width: 150px;"` (o el tamaño que desees) a la etiqueta :

```
<img src="${image}" style="width: 150px;" alt="" class="product-img">
```

3. Para solucionar la superposición, puedes forzar un fondo de color y después colocarlo por encima mediante z-index de este modo:

```
<div class="cart-products" id="products-id" style="background-color:white; z-index:100;">
```

a la vez que quitas esto de la clase **cart-products** en tu CSS:

```
height: 38px;
```

4. Y para solucionar la repetición de elementos agrega esto al principio de la función loadHTML():

```
  var children = Array.prototype.slice.call(containerBuyCart.childNodes)
  children.forEach(function(child) {
    containerBuyCart.removeChild(child);
  });
```

para que el contenido de containerBuyCart sea eliminado previamente antes de agregar de nuevo todo el array de elementos.

Te debería quedar todo eso junto así:

```js
let allContainerCart = document.querySelector('.shop-content');

let containerBuyCart = document.querySelector('.card-items')

let buyThings = [];


loadEventListener()

function loadEventListener() {

  allContainerCart.addEventListener('click', addProduct);

}

function addProduct(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  if (e.target.classList.contains('add-cart')) {

    const selectProduct = e.target.parentElement;

    readTheContent(selectProduct);

  }
}

function readTheContent(product) {

  const infoProduct = {

    image: product.querySelector('.product-img').src,
    title: product.querySelector('.product-title').textContent,
    price: product.querySelector('.price').textContent,
    id: product.querySelector('a').getAttribute('data-id'),
    amount: 1

  }

  buyThings = [...buyThings, infoProduct];

  loadHtml();

  console.log(infoProduct)

}

function loadHtml() {

  var children = Array.prototype.slice.call(containerBuyCart.childNodes)
  children.forEach(function(child) {
    containerBuyCart.removeChild(child);
  });

  buyThings.forEach(product => {

    const {
      image,
      title,
      price,
      amount,
      id
    } = product;

    const row = document.createElement('div');

    row.classList.add('product-box');

    row.innerHTML = `
            
            <img src="${image}" style="width:150px;" alt="" class="product-img">
            <h2 class="product-title">${title}</h2>
            <span class="price">${price}}</span>
            <a href="#" class="add-cart" data-id="${id}" >Añadir</a>
            <h6>Cantidad: ${amount}</h6> 

        `

    containerBuyCart.appendChild(row);

  });

}
```

```css
.nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1068px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  color: var(--color-violeta-fuerte);
  font-weight: 400;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.count-product {
  position: absolute;
  right: 3rem;
}

.cart-products {
  position: absolute !important;
  width: 39px;
  /* height: 38px; */
  right: 1rem;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.2rem;
  right: 2rem;
  top: 82px;
  padding: 0 18px;
  /*  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%); */
  min-width: 290px;
  display: none;
}

.cart {
  width: 39px;
  height: 38px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cart:hover {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  transition-duration: .5s;
}

#close-x {
  color: var(--color-rojo);
  font-weight: 900;
  background: var(--color-gris);
  padding: .2rem;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#close-x:hover {
  color: var(--color-rojo);
  background: var(--color-negro);
  padding: .3rem;
}

#cart-icon {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

section {
  padding: 4rem 0 3rem;
  margin-top: 2.5rem;
}

.section-title {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.shop {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.shop-content {
  padding-top: 170px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.shop-content .product-img {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 40vh;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
}

.product-box {
  position: relative;
}

.product-box:hover {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid var(--color-gris-oscuro);
  transition: .4s;
}

.product-title {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.price {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.add-cart {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: var(--color-gris-oscuro);
  color: var(--color-blanco);
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.add-cart:hover {
  background: var(--color-violeta-fuerte);
}
```

```html
<header>

  <div class="nav container">

    <a href="#" class="logo">E-Commerce</a>
    <img onmouseover="showCart(this)" class="cart" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAYAAADgdz34AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAR5JREFUSEvN1cExBUEUheHvRYAMiAARIAIywJYFIkAEbNgiAmRABIgAESAC6qqeV2PevOmuGqOczSz6zv379JnbMzKwRgP396eAz+TmHZc4+A13dQcVoOq7hru+kLYj2scJbrExBGAWb6nxAl76QKaFHBls9mj8iOV4fxpgCQ89AK+Y7wLEWuxiEdvpqyrhVc6PcZQDbOEigb7tZhTZPSOe4+xygxYzMZPOMxx1qdrQPVarwhzgFHu4QjToUszMSvNIc4AIKmyH5hCO2lTVfaRwx3U5QDS7wXq6OsJRmyLQwzanJYCY5utcwml94nopAdQ/2S7OE2J+fqgUUGhgsqwUcIYdnGO30aZrrfiHU7/Km5vqWisGDO5g8Az+L+ALYZk0GaU3ojwAAAAASUVORK5CYII="
      alt="carrito">
    <p class="count-product">0</p>

  </div>

  <div class="cart-products" id="products-id" style="background-color:white; z-index:100;">

    <p class="close-btn" id='close-x' onclick="closeBtn()">X</p>

    <h3>Mi carrito</h3>

    <div class="card-items">lala

    </div>

    <h2><strong class="price-total">0</strong></h2>

  </div>

</header>



<section class="products">

  <h2 class="section-title">Tienda de Productos</h2>

  <div class="shop-content">

    <div class="cart-items bg-success"> </div>

    <div class="product-box">

      <div>
        <img src="imagenes/taladro.png" alt="Taladro" class="product-img">
        <h2 class="product-title">Taladro 13mm</h2>
      </div>
      <span class="price">$15.000</span>
      <a href="#" class="add-cart" data-id="1">Añadir</a>
      <h6>Cantidad: 1</h6>
    </div>

    <div class="product-box">

      <div>
        <img src="imagenes/taladro-2.png" alt="Taladro" class="product-img">
        <h2 class="product-title">Taladro 10mm</h2>
      </div>
      <span class="price">$13.000</span>
      <a href="#" class="add-cart" data-id="1">Añadir</a>
      <h6>Cantidad: 1</h6>
    </div>

    <div class="product-box">

      <div>
        <img src="imagenes/amoladora.png" alt="Amoladora" class="product-img">
        <h2 class="product-title">Amoladora Angular</h2>
      </div>
      <span class="price">$9.999</span>
      <a href="#" class="add-cart" data-id="1">Añadir</a>
      <h6>Cantidad: 1</h6>
    </div>

    <div class="product-box">

      <div>
        <img src="imagenes/Grasera Manual.png" alt="Grasera" class="product-img">
        <h2 class="product-title">Grasera Manual</h2>
      </div>
      <span class="price">$13.000</span>
      <a href="#" class="add-cart" data-id="1">Añadir</a>
      <h6>Cantidad: 1</h6>
    </div>

    <div class="product-box">

      <div>
        <img src="imagenes/set-juego-de-herramientas.png" alt="Herramientas" class="product-img">
        <h2 class="product-title">Set Juego De Herramientas</h2>
      </div>
      <span class="price">$12.000</span>
      <a href="#" class="add-cart" data-id="1">Añadir</a>
      <h6>Cantidad: 1</h6>
    </div>

    <div class="product-box">

      <div>
        <img src="imagenes/cepillo-electrico.png" alt="Cepillo" class="product-img">
        <h2 class="product-title">Cepillo Eléctrico</h2>
      </div>
      <span class="price">$25.000</span>
      <a href="#" class="add-cart" data-id="1">Añadir</a>
      <h6>Cantidad: 1</h6>
    </div>

    <div class="product-box">

      <div>
        <img src="imagenes/cortadora-porcelanato.png" alt="Cortadora" class="product-img">
        <h2 class="product-title">Cortadora Porcelanato</h2>
      </div>
      <span class="price">$20.000</span>
      <a href="#" class="add-cart" data-id="1">Añadir</a>
      <h6>Cantidad: 1</h6>
    </div>

    <div class="product-box">

      <div>
        <img src="imagenes/Sierra-circular.png" alt="Sierra" class="product-img">
        <h2 class="product-title">Sierra Circular</h2>
      </div>
      <span class="price">$12.000</span>
      <a href="#" class="add-cart" data-id="1">Añadir</a>
      <h6>Cantidad: 1</h6>
    </div>

    <div class="product-box">

      <div>
        <img src="imagenes/lijadora-orbital.png" alt="Lijadora" class="product-img">
        <h2 class="product-title">Lijadora Orbital</h2>
      </div>
      <span class="price">$9.999</span>
      <a href="#" class="add-cart" data-id="1">Añadir</a>
      <h6>Cantidad: 1</h6>
    </div>

    <div class="product-box">

      <div>
        <img src="imagenes/soldadora.png" alt="Soldadora" class="product-img">
        <h2 class="product-title">Soldadora</h2>
      </div>
      <span class="price">$20.000</span>
      <a href="#" class="add-cart" data-id="1">Añadir</a>
      <h6>Cantidad: 1</h6>
    </div>

    <div class="product-box">

      <div>
        <img src="imagenes/dobladora-de-estribos.png" alt="Dobladora" class="product-img">
        <h2 class="product-title">Dobladora de Estribos</h2>
      </div>
      <span class="price">$9.999</span>
      <a href="#" class="add-cart" data-id="1">Añadir</a>
      <h6>Cantidad: 1</h6>
    </div>

    <div class="product-box">

      <div>
        <img src="imagenes/hidrolavadora.png" alt="hidrolavadora" class="product-img">
        <h2 class="product-title">Taladro</h2>
      </div>
      <span class="price">$15.000</span>
      <a href="#" class="add-cart" data-id="1">Añadir</a>
      <h6>Cantidad: 1</h6>
    </div>


  </div>

</section>

<script>
  function showCart(x) {
    document.getElementById("products-id").style.display = "block";
  }

  function closeBtn() {
    document.getElementById("products-id").style.display = "none";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Gracias como siempre; necesitaba terminar este código para poder estudiar unos cursos que me dieron y siempre me estanco en los archivos .js .

Comment: Me alegra que te haya funcionado :-)  He cambiado un poco tu pregunta agregándolo todo en un snippet completo en lugar de referencias externas, pues no son válidas en las preguntas por si desaparecen. Las preguntas deben ser autocontenidas para que las respuestas puedan entenderse siempre. Saludos!